# Can a Google Search Appliance that doesn't have a digital certificate scan sites that are SSL enabled?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, google-search-appliance

HTTPS has been enabled on a site and the Google Search Appliance now isn't able to crawl or access the site. My tech team can't figure out what is the issue and I haven't been able to find a definitive solution. Any help you can provide would be appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You should receive an error when using Real-time diagnostics but the best way, I've seen, is to use the "Forms Authentication" setup page.

Configure the sample URL to point to your site's home page and set the pattern to be the root URL for your site.

When you click "create" an SSL link will try to be created and you'll likely receive an error back at this point.

My guess is that the certificate on the web site may not be 'perfect' (the GSA is less forgiving than browsers are).